# Better alternative to shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs, web, browser

I'm using react motion for animations in my project.I solved the problem of rendering animations every time when prop change by maintaining state.

```
const {animation} = this.state;
        if (animation) {
            return (
                 // updates state upon animatioon to false
                 <Animator rest={this.rest}> 
                    {this.getContent()}
                </Animator>
            );
        }
        return this.getContent();
```

I have a call back that will change my state upon completing of animation.This solves all problems except props changing while animating.

Let's say my animation happens for 2 seconds and call back is triggered after that, but if animation is in the middle like 1 second and my props change then my animation again start from the beginning.

I don't want to use the `shouldComponentUpdate` as it will stop updating the view.

So how is this situation usually handled. Is it ok to use `shouldComponentUpdate`.Are there any better alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `componentWillReceiveProps` to handle the prop change? or is something directly bound to props?

Comment: @BradBumbalough above code is in my render function which renders when my props change

Answer (score 0):

If the animation component is rendered in this component (with name A), it will start from beginning every time A is re-rendered. So I think you can render the animation component in another component (B) which is a **sibling** of A and lies over A with a transparent background, or just use the animation component as the siblling. A and B can communicate via their parent or redux.