# shouldComponentUpdate alternative in React

Tags: reactjs

Note: [Better alternative to shouldComponentUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790546/better-alternative-to-shouldcomponentupdate) is a similar thread but does not have an answer.

React documentation says that shouldComponentUpdate may be only taken as suggestion in the future, and may be ignored.

Is there any alternative to stop a child component from re-rendering without shouldComponentUpdate?

Comment: Two things I would say, 1) this could (but isn't a strict solution) [componentwillreceiveprops](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) 2) do you need to worry about it?

Comment: Thank you Callum. Yes, it is not for the performance, but a need. One of the child components uses a media server and re-rendering messes it up.  I do not know how componentWillReceiveProps can prevent selective re-rendering at a state update. Can you please explain?

Comment: After thinking it through, I don't think you can explicitly prevent updates if the props change... I'm not 100% sure. But you can always know using this method when props change, so it may give you a chance to prevent an update?!

Comment: The docs have this to say about should update: If you determine a specific component is slow after profiling, you may change it to inherit from React.PureComponent which implements shouldComponentUpdate() with a shallow prop and state comparison. If you are confident you want to write it by hand, you may compare this.props with nextProps and this.state with nextState and return false to tell React the update can be skipped.